# How would I execute this command with NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to execute this task to record some music but I am getting errors. I am sure it's pretty simple:

```
sox -V6 -t coreaudio 'WavTap' --bits 16 test.wav
```

It's saying 'no such file or dir: wavtap'.

However, if I run it in the terminal it works fine. I am guessing something to do with the quotes throwing it off?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, although i don't know if this is what you're already doing.

```
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-V6", @"-t", @"coreaudio", @"'WavTap'", @"--bits", @"16", @"test.wav", nil];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
@try {
    [task setLaunchPath:pathOfSoxCommand];
    [task setArguments:args];
    [task launch];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.reason);
}
@finally {
    [task release];
}
```

Comment: looks good to me actually... the individual args become array elements. thats all

Comment: the line `NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:diffMergePath];` seems out of place though

Comment: @Daij-Djan Ooops, that was a copy-paste from one of my projects. Just fixed it. Thanks!